# React Native: Passing props to nested navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation

I'm using the slick React Navigation and following the [nested navigation recipe](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting) here, but i don't know how to pass 'this' to my navigation. Sorry for my ignorance.

Here is my general structure outline:

```
class MyApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StackNavigation
        screenProps={this.state}
      />
    )
  }
}

const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    Awesome: { screen: Awesome } // How do I pass this.state?
  }
)

const routesConfig = {
  Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
  Profile: { screen: Profile }
}

const StackNavigation = StackNavigator(routesConfig, {initialRouteName: 'Home'})
```

So how do I pass this.state to my MainScreenNavigator?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack), you can pass an extra option to the StackNavigator in the `StackNavigatorConfig`. Something like this:

`const StackNavigation = StackNavigator(routesConfig, StackNavigatorConfig)`

... where the `StackNavigatorConfig` is an object like:

`{ initialRouteName: 'Home', initialRouteParams: {...this.state} }`

And that is gonna pass all your **state** to the **initial route** of your navigator.

For **any other route** you can do:

`this.props.navigation.navigate('SomeScreen', {<the-greatest-object-for-pass-down>})`

And that is gonna pass **the-greatest-object-for-pass-down** to **SomeScreen**.

Finally, you can access to that params for **both** (the initial and any other screen) with `this.props.navigation.params`.

Comment: I guess my point is that `const StackNavigation` is declared outside the App component, so it has no context of `this` and `this` is not available

Comment: Youre right, I realize until now. But... What specifically do you wanna do? And why `screenProps` doesnt solve your problem?

Comment: So, this *works* for the initial render but I noticed if those props are modified (e.g. by modifying the state of the root component), the child screen doesn't rerender. Is there anyway to force the navigator to update its props?

Answer (score 3):

not sure if you can pass the state as-is. However the params you passed can be accessed by the next screen as follows.. you can try this

```
  this.props.navigation.state.params.<<property passes>>
```