# AWS Amplify Auth / react-navigation: How to access auth state?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, aws-amplify

In my [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native) mobile application, I would like to authenticate my users using [AWS Amplify Authentication](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication) and manage navigation between screens using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org). I tried to implement everything "by the book", i.e. as per the docs and my App *conceptually* looks like this:

```
// import statements skipped

class FirstTabScreen extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    {/* access some data passed in screenProps */}
    const someData = this.props.screenProps.someData;
    {/* TODO: how to access AWS Amplify auth data here ?!? */}
    {/* this.props contains screenProps and navigation objects */}
    console.log("this.props: ", this.props);
    {/* this.props.authState is undefined */}
    console.log("this.props.authState: ", this.props.authState);
    return <View><Text>First Tab - some data: {someData}</Text></View>
  };
}

class SecondTabScreen extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    const otherData = this.props.screenProps.otherData;
    return <View><Text>Second Tab - other data: {otherData}</Text></View>
  };
}

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  FirstTab: { screen: FirstTabScreen },
  SecondTab: { screen: SecondTabScreen },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      someData: null,
      otherData: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ someData: 'some data', otherData: 'other data' });
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <Authenticator>
        <AppContainer
          screenProps={{
            someData: this.state.someData,
            otherData: this.state.otherData,
          }}
        />
      </Authenticator>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

The code sample above skips a few important details; I have created a full [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@z00m1n/aws-amplify-auth-react-navigation).

The AWS Amplify `Authenticator` wraps the application and makes authentication data available to embedded components as e.g. `this.props.authState`; see [docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#customize-your-own-components).

**My problem** now is that I don't understand how to access this auth data in e.g. `FirstTabScreen`: In that component, `this.props` contains `screenProps` and `navigation` objects, but `this.props.authState` is `undefined`. With `AppContainer` and `AppNavigator` in between `Authenticator` and e.g. `FirstTabScreen`, I don't see how to pass auth data as props or transport them by some other means.

**Furthermore**, I just pass all data to all embedded components in `screenProps`; this does work, but not all screens require all data. How would I go about passing them only the data they actually require ? I know about [passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html), but all the code samples in there have a `Button` and use `this.props.navigation.navigate(...)` in the `onPress` handler. I don't have any buttons on those screens and don't need any - after all, navigating to a different tab is what the tabs in the bottom tab nav bar are for ?!?

Could anyone kindly shed some light on this for me ?

Comment: have you tried using redux? It is built for this type of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `screeProp` is [not encouraged on `react navigation v3`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/760#issuecomment-446926724)

> I believe it's no longer encouraged to put navigation such as TabNavigator nested within a component. I'm not quite sure how to handle such cases gracefully in V3. I wanted to upgrade from V1 to V3 recently and gave up on the upgrade since I couldn't find enough info on what to do with the nested navigators I have.

another idea from [esipavicius](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/760#issuecomment-376023906)

> do not wrap screens to stack navigator which include the tab navigator. Maybe you Can use `navigationAction` `setState` or `setParams` with `params` and `navigator` key. When You Can `dispatch` it. And automaticaly changes state with params to which scren you dispatched.

**OPTION 1 - USING SCREEN PROP**

Your option of [passing screen props](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46264894/7295772)

```
class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ someData: 'some data', otherData: 'other data' });
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <Authenticator>
        <AppContainer
          screenProps={{ myProp: "test" }}
        />
      </Authenticator>
    );
  };
}
```

**OPTION 2 - USING THE REACT CONTEXT API**

Using the [Context api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116444/7295772) and wrapping it around your `<AppContainer>`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    return (
      <FormContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <AppContainer />
      </FormContext.Provider>
    );
  };
}
```

Then consume it in each one of your screens.

```
class FirstTabScreen extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <FormContext.Consumer>
        { (context) => ( 
             // your logic 
        )}
      </FormContext.Consumer>
  };
}
```

**Option 3 - TAB NAVIGATOR OBJECT**

You can pass a [TabNavigatorObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44080924/7295772)

```
createBottomTabNavigator(RouteConfigs, BottomTabNavigatorConfig);
```

You can pass an extra option to the `BottomTabNavigator` in the `BottomTabNavigatorConfig`.

```
const BottomTabNavigator = StackNavigator(routesConfig, BottomTabNavigatorConfig)
```

The BottomTabNavigatorConfig is an option and you can check [the api docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html)

```
{ initialRouteName: 'Home', navigationOptions: .... }
```

**Option 4 - RETRIEVE PARAM FROM PARENT**

as [explained on github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3764#issuecomment-484431609) and in [the api docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/pt-BR/navigation-prop.html#dangerouslygetparent-get-parent-navigator), you can retrieve the parent component and then use `getParam`.

```
const parent = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
const yourParam = parent.getParam('yourParamName', 'default value')
```

You can find [many discussion about passing props with tab navigator on github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tab+navigator+passing+props+)

Answer (score 1):

**1)** I would suggest to not use any logic like this outside navigator. If you want login, do something like:

```
const rootStack = createSwitchNavigator({
    Login: { screen: LoginNavigator },
    Main: createBottomTabNavigator({
        FirstTab: { screen: FirstTabScreen },
        SecondTab: { screen: SecondTabScreen },
    });
})
```

It will give you more login possibilities and once you know user is loggedIn just navigate him to Main stack.

**2)** Use any store for app. For example `react-navigation` works great with `redux`. You can save all info there. 
Try to not use `screenProps` for simple cases like this. Also you don't need to send `authState` to other screens, just save to store.

**3)** Once you want logout. Do: `Auth.signOut()`, clean store, and navigate to Login screen.

Try to follow these simple steps and you will be able to implement much more complicated things